# How can indexes degrade MySQL performance?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've often heard that indexes can greatly improve performance, but sometimes they can reduce performance.

Other than just using memory, how can they reduce performance?

If I wish to optimize write time to a given table, but don't care about read time, would I be better of not using indexes (other than the PK)?

Comment: Just try adding a few hundred indexes in a table and measure write performance - before and after adding the indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writes and Updates have to create or amend indexed values. Therefore these can be slower when there are lots of indexes on a table. If you really don't care about read time at all then don't use indexes.

However good indexes will greatly improve read performance while only slightly degrading write performance, so only do this if reads really, really don't matter.

Comment: Thanks Andy.  It is for an audit table where I want it to have the least impact on the end user.  If I need to check data validity, I realize it will be a long query, but it typically will never be done.

Answer (score 3):

That's right -- if all you care about are writes, you should not use indexes. Any index will slow down your writes.

Indexes are designed to improve *read* performance. The general idea of an index is that it stores frequently-read data in a way that allows the database engine to access it more quickly, without having to scan the entire table to find that data. The tradeoff is that every time you write indexed data to a table, the index(es) must be updated as well. Therefore, indexes improve read performance, but degrade write performance.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, That is what I expected, but did not know for certain.